# ion row 50% of the screen

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, html5-video

I have a problem showing 2 videos in an ionic grid. Basically, I would like the two videos to take up the entire screen (50% height and 100% width each video). But I get this, the ion-row occupies 50% but the video inside is resized:

[image]

This is the code:
.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid class="design">

      <ion-row *ngIf="item0">
          <video oncontextmenu="return false;" class="center" id="video1" controls controlsList="nodownload">
            <source src="{{item0?.downloadURL}}" style="width:100%; height:100%" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="{{item0?.downloadURL}}" style="width:100%; height:100%" type="video/ogg">
          </video>
       </ion-row>



      <ion-row *ngIf="item1">
          <video oncontextmenu="return false;" class="center" id="video2" controls controlsList="nodownload">
            <source src="{{item1?.downloadURL}}"  style="width:100%; height:100%" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="{{item1?.downloadURL}}"  style="width:100%; height:100%" type="video/ogg">
          </video> 
      </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

.css:

```
.design {
  position: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ion-row {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%
}
```

I also tried to put the style="" in the video tag but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

By default, the videos will scale to fit the space given, while maintaining their file aspect ratio, which is why you get the result shown.

If you would like the video to occupy the whole space given, you will want to set the object-fit css to 'cover', i.e:

```
video {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```